# issue with format tag of JSTL in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, formatting, jstl

I have following code in my JSP Page-

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_vmeset-row.p51_vmeset)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm" />
<td style="${mm eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color:  pink'}">
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>
```

Through this code I want to display that whatever the result of subtraction if the fractional part display zero in the first two digits and zero in integer part ,then the result must be stored in variable mm and lime color should be displayed as maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" is equal to zero of the subtraction.

But what is displayed is that,if the result is zero then only lime is displayed.But **I want that if integer part and fractional part upto two digits is zero then also lime color should be display as background of column.**

Example -

> Suppose my r.p51_vmeset value is  -0.4000977 and row.p51_vmeset value
>   is -0.40009767 .Then the subtraction of both values will give
>   -0.0000003 but I want this to be trimmed as 00.00 and the color should be lime not pink.

I tried printing my result as-

```
 <fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p99_vmeset-row.p99_vmeset)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm" />
     **<c:out value="${mm}"></c:out>**
     <td style="${mm eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}" >
      <c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out></td>
```

The c:out shows value 00.00 But when i compare it in   that if mm is equal to zero background color should be lime but its showing pink.Y??

Comment: GIve some example of your number on which you want lime color

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to format your number to integer:

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="i" maxIntegerDigits="3" maxFractionDigits="0"
                   type="number" value="${mm}" />
```

and then compare here:

```
<td style="${i eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color:  pink'}">
```

Comment: I don't want it to convert it into Integer. But wants to trim it to following format ##.## and if this format has value as 00.00 then lime color should be there.

Comment: yes.The color will be lime only when after subtraction and trimming the values to ###.## the result is 00.00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have format ##.## for whatever value of subtraction, try this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

//use pattern="00.00"(0 represents a digit), instead of max/min
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_vmeset-row.p51_vmeset)}" pattern="00.00"  var="mm" />  

//remove "-" in case it's negative value
<c:set var="mm2" value="${fn:replace(mm, '-', '')}" />

//compare it with string '00.00', not number
<td style="${(mm2 eq '00.00') ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color:  pink'}">
<c:out value="${mm2}" ></c:out></td>
```

This should work, I just tested. Vote me up if works.

Comment: I want my integer to have any value  but fraction must be only upto two digits  i.e after subtraction the value can be ##.## or ###.## or ####.##. There is no problem of negative sign ,it can come. According to my requirement I can't compare (mm2 eq '00.00') as it can be 00.00 or 000.00.

Comment: Then why you set minIntegerDigits="2"? This is causing problem when you compare it with 0, it will be treated as string "00.xx", not number. I think you may have value like 132.22, 0.34, 0.00, can you explain in what case you want 00.## or 000.##, or 00000.##? It's hard to understand.

Comment: I have values of the format 0.45 and 45.78 and 345.00 .Ok I will not set minIntegerDigits="2".

Comment: After removing min IntegerDigits, then also I'm not getting my required results.

Comment: Try this: *100, then /100 before output (if you need):  `<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_vmeset-row.p51_vmeset)*100}" maxFractionDigits="0"  var="mm" />`, then compare it with 100 (it's bad practice to compare decimal number): `<td style="${mm eq 100 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color:  pink'}">`.  Before you output  it, format it back by /100 with your requirement.

Comment: but I don't understand what is the problem in my above code.Y its behaving so??

Comment: correct above condition: compare with 0, not 100:  `<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p51_vmeset-row.p51_vmeset)*100}" maxFractionDigits="0"  var="mm" />`, then compare it with  (it's bad practice to compare decimal number): `<td style="${mm <= 0? 'background-color: lime':'background-color:  pink'}">`.   By the way, you still need to remove "-" for negative value because you may get value "-1".

Comment: You code problem is `minIntegerDigits="2"`, this makes the number become a string in some cases, for example, if you use this hardcoded value to test: `<fmt:formatNumber value="${(0.41-0.40}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm" />`: mm is "00.01", this is string, not number, then when you compare it  `mm eq 0`, you will get exception. Try it.

Comment: I didn't get any exception

Comment: I should divide it by 100 when I c:out my value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73317/discussion-between-tiddi-rastogi-and-xli).